# How to support Multiple branch release using Jenkins Pipeline SCM Script?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have `SCM` plugin setup to build Jenkins pipeline.

For `Branches to build` option I have added the following 2 options-
`refs/heads/master` 
and 
`refs/heads/release`

I am triggering Jenkins using git hooks on the push of both of these branches.
Problem- on every push Jenkins build is happening through `master` branch so  `scm.branches[0].name` this variable is always giving me `master` as value regardless of the branch I have pushed.
How I can get different branches in `scm` so that I can use respective build processes for them.

Comment: Use `env.BRANCH_NAME` and an if statement?

Comment: To set `env.BRANCH_NAME` and use in `conditional statement` I need to set it using `scm` which is giving wrong branch name (always checkout to `master`).